# Is $\sqrt{x^2}$ equal to $|x|$, or to $\pm x$, or to both?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> If ${f(x) = \sqrt{x^2}}$, then f(x) can also be expressed as:
>
> C. $\;|x| \quad$ D. $\;\pm x$

I thought the answer was D, but it's C. Couldn't it be both?

Comment: When you are given $\sqrt{a}$, it is often implied that we are using the principal root, i.e. the positive one.

Comment: The symbol $\pm x$ denotes two numbers at once (except when $x=0$). So it does not define a function. But your $f$ here *is* a function.

Comment: The symbol $\pm x$ is senseless. What is used is something like $y=\pm x$ as shorthand for $y=x\lor y=-x$. No symbol can denote two different things (on a given context).

Comment: I learned the hard way that the answer is definitely C and _not_ D. The square root symbol stands for the principal square root (the positive one) in practice/by convention. In general, just because $a^2=b$ doesn't mean that $a=sqrt{b}$, just that $|a|=\sqrt{b}$. In other words $\sqrt{}$ doesn't mean "all square roots", it just means "the principal square root". Otherwise it would not define a function (since it would be multivalued).

Comment: For most complex values:$|a+bi|\ne\sqrt{(a+bi)^2}$ depending on what $|z|$ means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try with a number to see where the mistake is. Let's look at $f(4)$.

Then $f(4)$ = $\sqrt{16} = 4$, and we need to make sure that the options in C and D also give $4$.

In C, we get $4 = |4|$. So that works.

In D, we get $\pm 4$, which is a pair of numbers, both $4$ and $-4$. Well, $\pm 4 \neq 4$. In fact, there are two numbers on the left and only one on the right. So D is not right at all.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is convention.  The square root is part of a more general problem of finding the "roots" of a number (here $n$ is an integer $> 1$).  There are two ways to write the root of a number:

$$
x^n = a \rightarrow x = \sqrt[n]{a}\text{ or } x = a^\frac{1}{n}
$$

If you study complex analysis you will find that *every* number, real and complex, other than $0$, has exactly $n$ distinct roots (and if $n$ is an irrational number, it has an *infinite number* of roots!).  When you write $a^\frac{1}{n}$ you mean *all* roots (so this is not a function--it has many values) and when you write down $\sqrt[n]{a}$ you mean the *single*, positive, real value (here $a \geq 0$ and *must* be real).

Therefore when you do $\sqrt{x^2}$ it must always return a "positive" value (i.e. non-negative, meaning $0$ or positive)...which is the absolute value.  The problem is the fact that $x^2 = \left|x\right|^2$ so it could have just as easily been $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ or $\sqrt{\left|x\right|^2} = \left|x\right|$.  But since you know, in general $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x$, you choose the appropriate one...which is *always* the positive value--the absolute value.

Btw, notice that:

$$
\sqrt{x^2} =\left|x\right| =  \begin{cases} x & x> 0 \\
-x & x < 0 \\
0 & x = 0\end{cases}
$$

So your solution *does* involve $\pm x$ (i.e. sometimes it's $+x$ and sometimes it's $-x$).

Comment: So D is wrong since it does not specifically tell us when is $-$ and when $+$ should be taken into account. As such D is not a complete solution and hence wrong.+1.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, not $\pm x$. The latter, being multivalued, is not even a function in the standard sense.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=\pm x$ is not a function if the domain is not $\{0\}$.

$\sqrt{\cdot}:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is the "squared root" domain and codomain. That is, it is the principal square root.

To answer your question, yes it could be both. The important theme to consider is that a function is not just a "rule," because the domain is also a defining characteristic of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there seems to be some ambiguity: one may have in mind that square root of $a$ denote the solution of $x^2=a$, and since there are two solutions, square root is a [multivalued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function). But unless you are willing to do some complex analysis and study [Riemann surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface), it's a bad idea to go along that way.

So there is the definition of square root on $[0, +\infty[$: $\sqrt{a}$ is always the nonnegative solution of $x^2=a$.